# AmplifySignOut button only works if async function exists

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, aws-amplify

I am working on a simple React app that will use AWS Amplify to manage the user authentication.  On a protected profile page (wrapped in withAuthenticator) the `AmplifySignOut` button only works if there exists an async function inside the `Profile` component.  It doesn't even matter that it's not being called.

Here is my entry point file:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import awsconfig from 'src/aws-exports';
import Amplify from 'aws-amplify';

import Profile from './components/Profile';

Amplify.configure(awsconfig);

ReactDOM.hydrate(
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/bob">
        <Profile name="Bob" />
      </Route>
      <Route exact path="/susan">
        <Profile name="Susan" />
      </Route>
      <Route exact path="/mary">
        <Profile name="Mary" />
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('mountNode')
);
```

and here is my Profile component:

```
import React from 'react';
import Amplify from 'aws-amplify';
import awsconfig from '../aws-exports';
import { AmplifySignOut, withAuthenticator } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

Amplify.configure(awsconfig);

function Profile(props) {

  async function wtf() {}

  return (
    <div>
      Name: {props.name}
      <br />
      <Link to="/bob">Bob</Link>
      <Link to="/Susan">Susan</Link>
      <Link to="/Mary">Mary</Link>
      <br />
      <br />
      <AmplifySignOut />
      
    </div>
  );
}

export default withAuthenticator(Profile);
```

The code above works fine in that whenever I click the `Sign Out` button, it redirects me to the login modal.  But if I remove the `async` keyword (on that function that isn't even being called), then when I click on the `Sign Out` button, nothing happens.

I really don't want to keep that async function in there without knowing why it needs to be there.  Anyone have any ideas?